# Where is POM.XML in Eclipse JSF Project?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, maven

I am having problem when running my simple JSF hello-world like web app.

The tomcat says:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: conversion.Test
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - conversion.Test`

Now, I googled up and this link shows.

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-core-config/

I have downloaded jstl jar and put in inside lib folder under the tomcat home. But I still cannot understand and find the pom.xml. Where can i get this little guy?

Comment: pom.xml is a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) build configuration file. If you are not using Maven, adding a pom.xml will not help. The class missing is `conversion.Test`. This looks like something you have written. There is not enough information to address the problem.

Comment: @McDowell Ok now I understand it better. Yup, I am not doing a maven project. I am curious, how can I setup the Apache Tomcat 7 as most of the solution I bumped, not really working. I got the code works in Glassfish server and conversion.Test is not missing. It is there, I can't comprehend why Eclipse fail to put it up when running on Tomcat 7.

Comment: @McDowell could you please put that as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pom.xml is a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) build configuration file. If you are not using Maven, adding a pom.xml will not help. The class missing is conversion.Test. This looks like something you have written. There is not enough information to address the problem.